# JPA: Foreign key which only one from composite key

Tags: jpa, orm, composite-key

I'm having trouble getting a composite primary key and foreign keys working in JPA 2/Hibernate. I'm trying to create a simple scenario with A and B:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
    customer_id uuid,
    employee_id int,
    created_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
    
    CONSTRAINT customer_id_employee_id_pkey PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, employee_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_owner_owner_id FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
        REFERENCES public.owner (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

How should I create entity class ?

I tried below

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Data
public class CustomerId implements Serializable {
    private UUID customerId;
    private Long employeeId;
}


@Data
@Entity
@IdClass(CustomerId.class)
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -234295442215152987L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private UUID customerId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private Long employeeId;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "created_at", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime createdAt;
}
```

But I am not sure in which class should I map customer_id which is a foreign key.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

It should work this way

```
@Data
@Embeddable
public class CustomerId implements Serializable {
    private UUID customerId;
    private Long employeeId;
}


@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -234295442215152987L;

    @EmbeddedId
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private CustomerId customerId;


    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "created_at", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime createdAt;
}
```